# Is there any numerical technique to sum x^(n^alpha), n=0,1,...?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've come across this infinite series:  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^\alpha}$, with $0<x<1$ and $\alpha > 0$.

Does this series have a name and/or is there a method for computing it (besides brute force, obviously)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\alpha > 1$, this sum will converge extremely rapidly, even if $x$ is fairly close to $1$ (you can't express in floating point numbers those numbers close enough to $1$ where this would converge slowly).  The only case that is difficult, convergence wise, is when $\alpha$ is very close to 0.

In that case, your best bet are Levin's U-transform and related algorithms.  Even better, just link in to [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), which [already implements that](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Series-Acceleration-References.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "For $n\geq2$"?

Comment: And note the reference to the extensive review paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005209 found in the second link above.

Comment: @Jonas: I bet that's just a slip o' ye olde keyboard and shouldn't have been there. The answer seems to make good sense if you just delete it.

Comment: Yep, that $n\geq 2$ was a simple mistake [I had too many variants of the equation in my Maple session where I 'played around' with it first before posting my answer.  Error edited away, thanks]

Comment: I thought so.  I wouldn't mind all comments referring to it being deleted for posterity, but if I only delete mine it may be confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the case I'm interested in is 1/2 < alpha < 1, so the series converges pretty slowly.  Thank you for posting these links and this great review paper,  I will try this.    

Answer (score 2):

The $k$th power is the generating function for the ways of expressing $n$ as a sum of $k$ $\alpha$th powers of positive integers. However, I don't think this helps much even for most integer values of $\alpha$.

When $\alpha = 1$, this is a geometric series.

When $\alpha = 2$, this is a [theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) related to the [Jacobi triple product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)

$$\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-x^{2m})(1+x^{2m-1}y^2)(1+x^{2m-1}y^{-2}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2}y^{2n}$$
since 
$$ (\frac 12 \text{RHS}+\frac12) \bigg|\_{y=1} = \sum\_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} .$$

You may be able to compute the sum when $\alpha=2$ more efficiently using one of the integral formulas or other properties for elliptic theta functions. Other than that, I don't know of special cases.

This doesn't say anything about whether some rapid series acceleration technique exists.

Comment: For $\alpha=2$ you can use the functional equation for the theta function to get a massive speed-up. Set $\theta(t)=\sum_ne^{-\pi n^2 t^2}$, where the sum is over all integers. This converges for $t>0$ real. Much less clear, but completely standard, is that $\theta(1/t)=t\theta(t)$. Using this trick you can reduce to the case $0<t\leq 1$ which corresponds to $0<x<0.0432...$ where the series is converging super-fast.

Comment: As an explicit example, if $x=0.9$ and $\alpha=2$ then summing 1000 terms gives an answer of  3.230272... . But solving $e^{-t^2}=x$ gives t=0.183... so $u:=1/t=5.4605...$ and summing just _one_ term for the series with $x=e^{-\Pi u^2}$ gives 1, correct to 40 or so dec places, so $\theta(t)$ is approximately $u$ (to about 40 dec places!) so the sum we're interested in is hence (1+u)/2. In summary, the answer with $x=0.9$ and $\alpha=2$ is very very close to $(1+u)/2$ with $u=(-\log(0.9)/\pi)^{-1/2}$. As $x$ gets closer to 1 this formula gets better and better.

Comment: [...and if you want more accuracy then use more than _one_ term when expanding $\theta(u)$!]

Comment: [aargh slip above "reduce to the case $t\geq1$". When can we edit comments??

Comment: For $\theta(1/t)=t\theta(t)$ read $\theta(1/t)=\sqrt{t}\theta(t)$.
(Not that this helps much with the original question).
So again, when can we edit comments?

Comment: My definition of the theta function is non-standard Robin (I put the square in already) so I think I'm OK. Mea culpa for using the wrong definition, of course. I think the problem with editing comments is that math overflow is running on software written by someone else so you have to request changes to a higher god who is not always benevolent. If you feel strongly about it, ask at tea.mathoverflow.net and they'll explain the procedure.

Comment: Sorry Kevin, I ought to learn how to read :-(